# Calculate astronomical distance of two set of sky position with theano

Tags: python, python-3.x, theano, astronomy

I want to compute the [angular distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_distance) between all points in two different sets, something like `cdist` of `scipy` but with a different distance algorithm and using theano. The angular distance between two sources with right ascension (ra) in (0,2pi) and with declination (dec) in (-pi/2, pi/2) is:

```
theta = arccos(sin(dec1)*sin(dec2)+cos(dec1)*cos(dec2)*cos(ra1-ra2))
```

suppose that `X` is a matrix consists of `N` sources with their position `(ra, dec)`:

```
#RA     DEC 
54.29   -35.19  
54.62   -35.45
...
```

and `W` is other set of sources `M` different sources. How can I determine the angular separation of all `X` sources with all `W` sources?

Inspired to the euclidian distance:

```
edist = T.sqrt((X ** 2).sum(1).reshape((X.shape[0], 1)) + (W ** 2).sum(1).reshape((1, W.shape[0])) - 2 * X.dot(W.T))
```

I have tried with:

```
d = T.arccos(\\
T.sin(X.reshape((X.shape[0], 1, -1))[...,1])*T.sin(W.reshape((1, W.shape[0], -1))[..., 1])+\\
T.cos(X.reshape((X.shape[0], 1, -1))[...,1])*T.cos(W.reshape((1, W.shape[0], -1))[..., 1])*\\
T.cos(X.reshape((X.shape[0], 1, -1))[...,0] -W.reshape((1, W.shape[0], -1))[...,0]))
```

that resulting `d` matrix has shape `(N, M)` instead of `(N, M, 2)`, since I expected to sum over the third axis; further the numerical result is wrong (I have compared it with [TOPCAT](http://www.star.bris.ac.uk/~mbt/topcat/) which is a software astronomy-oriented. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue: simply i have to convert right ascension and declination from degree to radian. Now, the method works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to debug your expression by parts - calculate `sin(dec1)` first and make sure you get the right shape and the right numerical result. Then the multiplication with `sin(dec2)` and so on until you get the full `arccos` expression.

One idea of something that is possibly wrong with your code is the use of `*` for multiplication - if you want to multiply matrices you should use `T.multiply()` instead of `*`.